# Running system commands in Java through a config file

Tags: java, cmd

How do I run commands that are present in a config file through the same Java code? I want to run command line scripts through the same Java code; I could run it when I hardcode it but I want to run these commands from a config file, please let know how to do?

```
    try { 
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
        Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir"); 
        Process pr = rt.exec("C:/bea/wlserver_10.3/server/bin/setWLSEnv.cmd && java weblogic.Admin -url server:port -username system -password passwd CLUSTERSTATE -clusterName cluster");
         BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
        String line=null; 
        while((line=input.readLine()) != null) 
        { 
          System.out.println(line); 
          int exitVal = pr.waitFor(); 
          System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal); 
         }
}finally{
}}}} catch(Exception e)
```

How do I run the commands in argument for exec from a xml config file,the commands that I ve put there are going to be in an xml config file, I want tun these commands from there.

Answer (score 2):

Your old friend `Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`

```
try {
    String str ="C:/somefile.txt";
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c",str});
    System.out.println(str);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
```

You can also refer [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/).

Comment: do not post your code in comment, please post it in your question.